# Testing for an exception with part of the message with Codeception

Tags: php, exception, message, codeception

I'm using Codeception for my testing, and I need to check that an exception is thrown. I've done so like this:

```
$I->expectException('Exception', function() use ($service, $data, $I) {
        $service->parse($data);
    });
```

I'd like to check if the exception message contains part of a string as well, so if the entire message is something like **"Incorrect line length on line 5. Expected blah blah blah"**, I'd like to test that it at least has the first part, **"Incorrect line length"**.

I know how to do that with PHPUnit. Can it be done with Codeception?

Answer (score 0):

All features of PhpUnit can be used in Test format, but if you are using Cept or Cest format you will have to write your own helper.

Copy, rename and modify [expectException](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/02ee5b75eed804a75c3bfc43b08a3fda25fc4f8a/src/Codeception/Module/Asserts.php#L361) method provided by Codeception.